# Удаление константных столбцов в C#

Tags: c#

Есть матрица `List<double[]>`. Нужно удалить столбцы, которые не изменяются у каждой строки, например есть матрица:

```
0 1 2 3
1 1 3 3
3 1 4 3
4 1 2 3
```

Нужно удалить тут 2й и последний столбцы. Может можно это сделать нативными методами? Спасибо.

Comment: Как пробовали решить задачу?

Comment: @tym32167 Думаю, что можно в лоб написать цикл с флагом, если значение не равно предыдущему, то флаг меняем и по концу если флаг не менялся, то удаляем столбец. Но может есть какой-нибудь красивый метод, который можно использовать в 1 строку...

Comment: @Max: Ну цикл с флагом можно оформить через LINQ, а так особо выиграть не получится.

Comment: А как можно будет удалить столбец?

Comment: Что у вас строки, а что столбцы в выражении `List<double[]>`? Если `double[]` описывает столбец - просто удаляйте его из листа, для этого есть метод Remove. А если строку, то все печально. придется пересоздать все строки в укороченном виде.

Comment: @rdorn как раз второе... печально

Comment: @Max, c Linq можно в 1 строчку, но это самый неэффективный способ ```var res = data.Select(row => row.Where((r,i)=> Enumerable.Range(0, data.Count).Select(di=>data[di][i]).Distinct().Count() > 1).ToArray()).ToList();``` Лучше написать алгоритм самому руками - будет гораздо эффективнее

Comment: Внесите уточнения в вопрос, по поводу сопоставления строк и столбцов применительно к объявленной структуре данных. Это существенная информация. Ну и еще вопрос вдогонку, у вас есть возможность заменить структуру данных на что-то более удобное или нет?

Comment: @rdorn List - строки, double[] - столбцы. Вы имеете ввиду могу ли я поменять строки и столбца местами?

Comment: @Max, если есть возможность поменять местами, то задача значительно упростится: `data.Where(column => column.Distinct().Count() > 1).ToList()`

Comment: @Max, он имеет в виду `List<List<double>>` - можно или нельзя?

Answer (score 2):

Если double[] - это строки, то, как вариант, можно преобразовать матрицу в
List < List < double > >:

```
static class Converter<T>
{
    public static List<List<T>> ToListsOfLists(List<T[]> matrix) {
        var result = new List<List<T>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < matrix[0].Length; i++)
            result.Add(new List<T>());
        for (var i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].Length; j++)
                result[i].Add(matrix[j][i]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

А затем уже удалить нужные столбцы:

```
private static void DeleteEqualColumns(List<List<double>> matrix) {
        var index = 0;
        while (index < matrix.Count) {
            var columnIsEqual = true;
            var firstElementInColumn = matrix[index][0];
            for (var i = 1; i < matrix[0].Count - 1; i++)
                if (firstElementInColumn != matrix[index][i]) {
                    columnIsEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (columnIsEqual)
                matrix.Remove(matrix[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Если double[] - это столбцы, то все достаточно просто, так как удалять столбцы можно, используя команду класса List.Remove(column);

```
private static void DeleteEqualColumns(List<double[]> matrix) {
        var index = 0;
        while (index < matrix.Count) {
            var columnIsEqual = true;
            var firstElementInColumn = matrix[index][0];
            for (var i = 1; i < matrix[index].Length - 1; i++)
                if (firstElementInColumn != matrix[index][i]) {
                    columnIsEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (columnIsEqual)
                matrix.Remove(matrix[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Используется while, а не for, потому что когда удаляется столбец, Count у List изменяется, а переменная-счетчик i у for не изменяется, и неизбежен выход за пределы массива.

Comment: В комментариях написано, что нет.

Comment: Что значит "нет"?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725501/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-c/725522?noredirect=1#comment1095913_725501